# Android app layout issue for vector xml drawable file in different screen resolutions

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, svg

I am facing a screen compatibility issue when I tried to add as svg image as vector to my layout file. My code is below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.auth.AuthActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/otNum"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/otpIcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_otp_image"/> <--  ic_otp_image.xml  in drawable -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_below="@id/otpIcon"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="50dp">

            <!-- Some form content goes here-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am doing my development on a device which is of xxhdpi, ie on a direct device. The above layout setting works fine on this device, but when I did a device compatibility test on an emulator (hdpi 480 x 800). The image takes more than half the screen size of the device and  all my form content goes out of  the screen. I have checked different post but could not find the correct solution for this issue.

Screenshot of hdpi(left) and (xhdpi) simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by [setting the height and width of the drawable using dimens.xml files](https://medium.com/@suragch/using-dimens-xml-in-android-10dec2fe485c#:%7E:text=Supporting%20multiple%20screen%20sizes&text=That%20way%20you%20could%20do,and%20choose%20Smallest%20Screen%20Width.). This will let you define different sizes for the drawable depending on the size of the screen.

You could also solve it with a `ConstraintLayout`. Below is one such solution. This code will make the `ImageView` take up 40% of the screen width, and its width:height ratio will be 2:1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
    android:background="@drawable/myDrawable"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But the button still goes down since I have 2 different devices with different heights but both come under xxhdpi, So I think a percentage height value will be an ideal solution instead of making different values folder

Comment: You want to use the `smallest-width` qualifier. For instance, sw500dp will get used if the smallest width of the device is >=500dp. And you could set another one at sw390dp if you want, which will be used on devices >=390 but < 500.